# No Duplicate Primary Key

Tags: c#, sql, primary-key

I am working on a school activity. This is my sample form:

[sample form http://i53.tinypic.com/14xlrl.png](http://i53.tinypic.com/14xlrl.png)

What I'm trying to do is that when a user adds a record that has the same CourseID (Primary Key) with one of the records listed, there should be some Message box that will appear that says "Cannot insert same CourseID or cannot duplicate CourseID (Because PRIMARY KEY cannot be DUPLICATED)."

Comment: Many of us know the answer, but what have you tried?

Comment: I hate to say it, but I know what two things haven't been tried, learning about primary key constraints and error checking...

Comment: And what currently happens in your app when you try to do this?  A crash?  Does the record get inserted even though it is a dupe?  Please edit your question to add this info (and John's - I agree with his question as well).

Comment: @albanx Merlyn ***does not have the ability*** to delete your comment. It was deleted by the system, after attracting multiple flags. The only disrespect here is yours.

Comment: yea yea yea that's all folks says, by the system

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham No, the record doesn't get inserted when there's already a record in the database with the same Primary key. An error message shows up.

Comment: @Kristina: Can you provide the error message text, or at least a screenshot?  I am thinking you already have your DB set up correctly, and you just need to catch an exception when you try to add the entry.  Also, running through the "add to db" code in your debugger might be a good thing to try.

Comment: @Merlyn I already provided my working code below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are manually inserting CourseID. A better way is to make the CourseID column auto-incrementing in SQL Server.

Secondly, if you seriously created a primary key, it won't accept duplicates. You only need to catch the Exception. Check these links on Exception Handling:

[Throwing Exceptions in C#](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/CSharpThrowingExceptions.aspx)

[Exceptions and Exception Handling (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173160%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Your `Course_ID` column looks to be redundant. Suggestion: drop `Course_ID` and declare a unique constraint on `Course_Code` using a meaningful name. When an update would cause a duplicate `Course_ID` value, the DBMS will automatically reject the update and generate an erro. You should ensure this error is exposed to your application, including the meaningful name, for your application to handle gracefully.

Answer (score 0):

As said by others, don't let the user enter the primary key. However if you really must.

```
Select Count(*) from tablename where CourseID = [whatever]
```

If Count returns 1, then it means there's already a record with that id, and throw an error.

An alternative is to just try the Insert function which should throw an exception, then handle that.